# Gurobi, need help to improve constrain adding time

Tags: python, optimization, traveling-salesman, constraint-programming, gurobi

I am modeling problem to solve by gurobi optimization module, but it is a huge. However, I am going to try to explain it based on a simple Traveling Salesman kind problem,

*A* is a list that contains the value of net profit by visiting any city from 0 to n
*precedences* is the precedences of any *i* city in *A* list, so it could be something like precedences=[[1,3,5],[0,2,5]....], so for city 0 the previous cities that must be visted before going city 0 are city1,city3 and city5.

the problem must be solved satisfying some constrains like time or periods used, every period limited by minimum cities visited and minimun income recibed and a maximum numbers of period that could be solve the problem.

so, I have modeled like this:
    from gurobipy import *

```
# data for problem

A=citiesvalue
Pc=precedences


Periods=range(7)
Disccount_rate=[0.9090909090909091, 0.8264462809917354, 0.7513148009015775, 0.6830134553650705, 0.6209213230591549, 0.5644739300537772, 0.5131581182307065]

m = Model()
n = len(A) # number of cities

# Indicator variable for each city
x = {}
for prd in Periods:
    for i in range(n):
        x[i,prd] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%d%d" %(i,prd))



m.update()
obj=(quicksum((quicksum(A[i]*x[i,prd] for i in range(n)))*Disccount_rate[prd] for prd in Periods))
# Set objective
m.setObjective(obj,GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Add constraints
#this contrain prevents salesman go to city0 without going to its precedences cities at any period p
for e in range(0,len(Pc)):
    for p in Periods:
        for j in Pc[e]:
        m.addConstr(x[u,p] <= x[v,p])
#this constrain prevents that a citie that was visited in a period 0 must be visited at periods>0 if it is at any precedence 
for p in Periods:
    for u in range(len(A)):
        m.addConstr(x[u,p-1]<=x[u,p])
#this constrain prevent that in any period income be less than a certain number
m.addConstr(quicksum((A[i])*x[i,prd] for i in range(n) for prd in Periods))<=7500000)
```

as you can see it is some kind of simple problem, but mine is really huge and the precedences for each item at *A* too, so the constrain adding is having soo much time to finish, so i let it for more than 24 hrs an it got stuck for memory lacking.